# Trading with S&P 500 options

Tags: options, spx

Could someone help me who has experience with trading S&P 500 options? I am curious about any **liquidity trends** (if OTM, ATM, ITM are the most liquid, and with what kind of maturity), and the average **bid-ask spread** on the option contracts. Also, any comments on the usability of **trading platforms** (like Interactive Brokers) would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the usability of trading platforms"? There is a myriad of ways to use a trading platform.

Comment: Ironically the biggest difficulty in trading SP500 options is that there are so many liquid strikes and expirations available to trade. Different systems (Bloomberg, vs Reuters vs IB, etc.) use different symbols to refer to them, that it can be challenging to quickly find, quote and trade the right one in whatever UI you need. For the other questions, why not explore the market yourself: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5ESPX/options It is one of the widest and deepest option markets. And if not deep enough for you, you can also access options on SPY (S&P 500 ETF) or on S&P 500 futures....